# Copy and paste data from one sheet to multiple where range matches sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

I have an API call that pulls data relating to 34 individual sites. Each site has a varying number of assets within it, each with a unique identifier.

I am trying to write a macro that will copy and paste the data for specific sites into their own individual worksheet within the file. The basic concept of this I am familiar with but I am struggling with the ranges I need to specify.

So basically, I need the macro to work its way down Column A of the sheet called Raw Data and identify any rows where the Site name (Value in column A) matches one of the Sheet names. It should then copy the Rows from A to H with that site name and paste into the respective site sheet in rows A to H.

The values in Column A will always match one of the other sheets in the workbook.

Example image that might help explain a bit better:
[image: Example image that might help explain a bit better]

Apologies in advance if my explanation is not very clear. I have very limited experience using macros so I am not sure if my way of explaining what I want to achieve is understandable or if at all possible.

I am very keen to learn however and any guidance you fine folk could offer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "I am trying to write a macro" - that's a good start. Please post your efforts so far. You will find examples of this problem online. The steps are (1) create a list of unique sites (2) loop through each extracting the relevant records using autofilter (3) copy filtered records to a new sheet.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see  [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Try this one

```
Function ChkSheet(SheetName As String) As Boolean

    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = SheetName Then
            ChkSheet = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    ChkSheet = False

End Function

Sub test()
Dim i, j, k As Long
Dim wsRaw As Worksheet
Dim Aux As String

Set wsRaw = Worksheets("Raw Data")

For i = 1 To wsRaw.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If ChkSheet(wsRaw.Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then
        Aux = wsRaw.Cells(i, 1).Value2
        k = Worksheets(Aux).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
        For j = 1 To 8
            Worksheets(Aux).Cells(i + k, j).Value2 = wsRaw.Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next
    Else
        Worksheets.Add.Name = wsRaw.Cells(i, 1).Value2
        Aux = wsRaw.Cells(i, 1).Value2
        k = 2
        For j = 1 To 8
            Worksheets(Aux).Cells(i + k, j).Value2 = wsRaw.Cells(i, j).Value2
        Next
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

So the Function ChkSheet will check if the sheet exist (you don´t need to create them) and the procedure test will follow all the items that you have in your "Raw Data" worksheet and it will copy to the last used row of every sheet.

And please, even for a newbie, google, read, get some information and when you get stacked, ask for help. This forum is not for giving solutions with not effort.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning all,

David, thanks very much for your help with this. I really didn't want you to think I was trying to get someone to give me the answer and I had tried a few other things before asking the question, but I neglected to show any evidence of my workings. Rookie mistake and I apologise for this.

Having done a bit more research online and with a good dollop of help from a much more experienced colleague I have got the below code using advance filter which works perfectly for what I need.

I thought I would share it here in case it is of any use to others in the future.

```
    Option Explicit

Dim RawDataCol As String
Dim ListCol As String
Dim AdvRng As String
Dim RawDataRng As String
Dim SiteAbrRng As String
Dim ShiftCols As String
Private Sub SetParameters()

'Cell Address where RawData is pasted to each of the site sheets
    RawDataCol = "A2"

'Column where the Unique List is cleared and pasted
    ListCol = "L"

'Advanced Filter Range
    AdvRng = "A1:K2"

'Pasted Raw Data Columns on each sheet
    RawDataRng = "A2:K"

'Site Abr gets pasted to the address during loop
    SiteAbrRng = "A2"

'Range that gets deleted after pasting Raw Data to each sheet
    ShiftCols = "A2:K2"

End Sub
Sub CopyDataToSheets()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

AppSettings (True)

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    StartTime = Timer

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sht_RawData As Worksheet, sht_target As Worksheet, sht_AdvancedFilter As Worksheet, sht_TurbineData As Worksheet
Dim tbl_RawData As ListObject
Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long, UniqueListCount As Long
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim ArrTest As Boolean
Dim x As Long, AdvRowNo As Long

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

SetParameters

Set sht_RawData = wbk.Worksheets("Raw Data")
Set sht_AdvancedFilter = wbk.Worksheets("Advanced Filter")
Set sht_TurbineData = wbk.Worksheets("Turbine Data")

Set tbl_RawData = sht_RawData.ListObjects("_00")

'clear unqie list of SiteAbr
With sht_TurbineData

    LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row

    If LastRow1 > 1 Then
        'sht_TurbineData.Range("L1:L" & LastRow1).ClearContents
        sht_TurbineData.Range(ListCol & 1 & ":" & ListCol & LastRow1).ClearContents
    End If

End With

'Copy Unqiue list of SiteAbr to Turbie Data Sheet
tbl_RawData.Range.Columns(1).AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=sht_TurbineData.Range(ListCol & 1), _
    Unique:=True

    LastRow1 = sht_TurbineData.Cells(Rows.Count, sht_TurbineData.Range(ListCol & 1).Column).End(xlUp).Row

    'Sort Unique List
    sht_TurbineData.Range("L1:L" & LastRow1).Sort _
    Key1:=sht_TurbineData.Range("L1"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlYes

'Load unique site Abr to array
With sht_TurbineData

    'MyArr = Application.Transpose(.Range("L2:L" & LastRow1))
    MyArr = Application.Transpose(.Range(ListCol & 2 & ":" & ListCol & LastRow1))

    UniqueListCount = LastRow1 - 1

End With

'Test Array conditions for 0 items or 1 item

ArrTest = IsArray(MyArr)

If UniqueListCount = 1 Then
    MyArr = Array(MyArr)

ElseIf UniqueListCount = 0 Then
    GoTo ExitSub

End If

    For x = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

        Set sht_target = wbk.Worksheets(MyArr(x))

                With sht_target

                    'Find the last non blank row of the target paste sheet
                    LastRow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                    'Clear contents if the Last Row is not the header row
                    If LastRow2 > 1 Then
                        .Range(RawDataRng & LastRow2).ClearContents
                    End If

                    sht_AdvancedFilter.Range(SiteAbrRng) = MyArr(x)

                    'Filter Source Data and Copy to Target Sheet
                    tbl_RawData.Range.AdvancedFilter _
                        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                        CriteriaRange:=sht_AdvancedFilter.Range(AdvRng), _
                        CopyToRange:=.Range(RawDataCol), _
                        Unique:=False

                    'Remove the first row as this contains the headers
                    .Range(ShiftCols).Delete xlShiftUp

                End With

    Next x

ExitSub:
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 3)

    AppSettings (False)

    'Notify user in seconds
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation



Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox (Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description)
    GoTo ExitSub

End Sub
Sub ClearAllSheets()

Dim tbl_SiteList As ListObject
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sht_target As Worksheet, sht_TurbineData As Worksheet
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim x As Long, LastRow As Long

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set sht_TurbineData = wbk.Worksheets("Turbine Data")
Set tbl_SiteList = sht_TurbineData.ListObjects("SiteList")

SetParameters

MyArray = Application.Transpose(tbl_SiteList.DataBodyRange)

For x = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

    Set sht_target = wbk.Worksheets(MyArray(x))

        LastRow = sht_target.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If LastRow > 1 Then
            sht_target.Range("A2:K" & LastRow).ClearContents
        End If

Next x

End Sub
Private Sub AppSettings(Opt As Boolean)

If Opt = True Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ElseIf Opt = False Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End If

End Sub
```

Thanks again to all who answered and especially to you David. Although I have only used the basic principles from what you offered, it was extremely useful to help me understand what I needed to do in order to get the data to copy into the correct sheets.

Many thanks,
MrChrisP